# Cannot start Rubycas-Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to start rubycas-server with 'rubycas-server', I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: activesupport(3.0.1 not = 2.3.5) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rubycas-server:18
```

I have also tried rubycas-server-ctl start --verbose but I get the same thing except the last line is "from /usr/bin/rubycas-server-ctl:18". I only have activesupport 3.0.1 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install activesupport 2.3.5 and uninstall activesupport 3.0.1

```
gem uninstall activesupport -v=3.0.1
gem install activesupport -v=2.3.5
```